# how do i setup maraDNS in windows7 as forwarding DNS server for 2 zones : the intranet and the default (aka "everything else")

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I am trying to setup maraDNS on windows 7. All in all I want the google DNS to resolve everything (zone "1" so to speak) apart from everything in the intranet domains, which as served by an intranet DNS server.

So I have added in `mararc`

```
hide_disclaimer = "YES"
ipv4_bind_addresses = "127.0.0.1"
timestamp_type = 2
random_seed_file = "secret.txt"

upstream_servers = {}
upstream_servers["."]="8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" # Servers we connect to
upstream_servers["intranet.lan."]="1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5"
upstream_servers["intra.lan."]="1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5"
```

this gives a

```
> askmara.exe Agoogle.com.
# Querying the server with the IP 127.0.0.1
# Remote server said: REFUSED
# NS replies:
# AR replies:
```

Then I tried with the "csv2" variable and a text file

```
upstream_servers = {}
upstream_servers["."]="8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" # Servers we connect to

csv2 = {}
csv2["intranet.lan."]="db.intr.lan"
csv2["intra.lan."]="db.intr.lan"
```

where text file "db.intr.lan" contains:

```
intranet.lan.    NS nameserver1.intranet.lan ~
intra.lan.       NS nameserver1.intranet.lan ~
```

but this gives out this warning

```
Processing zone asw.zone. right now.
Filename: db.eb.txt
Warning: Authoritative NSes must be immediately after SOA
Or the first records in the zone
Otherwise, the record is ignored
Processing zone elektrobit.com. right now.
Filename: db.eb.txt
```

but I really don't thing adding a "SOA" record here is the correct way.

I do not want to create an authoritative name server for my intranet. Just to forward different domains to different nameservers and obviously have a default DNS to be at google. How do I do that?

Thank you
So how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'm not familiar with maraDNS, so my answer won't answer your question, but If you'd like to try another solution I'll try to show how to do that on well supported `unbound` DNS forwarder (especially author of maraDNS said "Since MaraDNS is in deep freeze — I only fix security and other serious bugs ")

First we need to tell `unbound` about private IP ranges

```
# Only 'private-domain' and 'local-data' names are allowed to have these private addresses.
private-address: 10.0.0.0/8
private-address: 172.16.0.0/12
private-address: 192.168.0.0/16
private-address: 169.254.0.0/16
private-address: fd00::/8
private-address: fe80::/10
```

Then tell `unbound` about local(private) domains

```
private-domain: "intra.lan."
domain-insecure: "intra.lan."

local-zone: "intra.lan."             nodefault      # nodefault prevent leak of query to outside

# override defaults with stub-zones
local-zone: "168.192.in-addr.arpa." nodefault
```

Then we can reroute local DNS query to the local DNS that is responsible for name resolution on "intra.lan." and anything else will be resolved by upstream DNS servers

```
forward-zone:
    name: "intra.lan."
    forward-addr: 192.168.xx.yy  # IP address of DNS responsible for "intra.lan."

stub-zone:
    name: "xx.168.192.in-addr.arpa."
    stub-addr: 192.168.xx.yy
```

(replace xx and yy with actual IP)

Comment: Hi there, what do I need the stub zone for ?  Also there are no local private domains. There is a default name server - which I want to be different from the dhcp provided one and a secondary name server elsewhere that serves the local net.

Comment: "intra.lan." is private local domain, probably it served by "a secondary name server elsewhere that serves the local net". check "ipconfig" what domain suffix applied by default on computers, if it isn't real internet domain then it is private local one. The stub zone can be used to configure authoritative data to be used by  the resolver that cannot be accessed using the public internet servers. This is useful for  company-local  data  or  private  zones.